# Parametros em HTML

Tags: html, html5

Sou novo em assunto de HTML, estou fazendo um trabalho pra faculdade onde só podemos utilizar HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JSP, Servlet, Java e banco MySQL. Ate agora criei uma pagina com algumas imagens, e um nome pra cada imagem, e quando clico em uma imagem, sou redirecionado a outra pagina para se preencher um formulário. O que preciso saber é, como faço para que o nome, que esta abaixo da imagem, possa assim que redirecionado, já ir para um dos campos do formulário.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Inclua o seu código

Comment: É bom novos usuários no site, mas é bom também ler a página [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o funcionamento. Como está aprendendo HTML, é interessante aprender tb a usar termos mais específicos: "_o nome, que esta abaixo da imagem_".... Esse **nome** a que se refere seria apenas um **texto**, e para capturá-lo é necessário conhecer a estrutura que está usando. Por isso é importante colocar o trecho do HTML na pergunta, porque senão não tem como dar uma resposta precisa, porque esse **texto** pode ser capturado de várias formas, dependendo de como ele está no cód.

Answer (score 0):

### A solução

Essa prática é denominada "bookmark".

Para fazer isso, você precisa colocar um id no campo que deseja ter foco, na outra página.

```
<input type="button" id="foo">
```

E na url do texto, você deve adicionar uma **cerquillha seguida do id alvo** (#foo):

```
<a href="http://www.exemplo.com/outra-pagina#foo"></a>
```

### Exemplo funcional e similar ao seu problema

```html
<a href="#foo">Me leve ao foo!</a>

<h1>Bar</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>

<h1>Biz</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>

<h1 id="foo">Foo</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>
<h1>Bet</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>

<h1>Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>

<h1>Bat</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>

<h1>Fitz</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis rutrum diam at iaculis. Nam nec suscipit quam. Aenean vestibulum metus sit amet ultrices scelerisque. Praesent porttitor est at mi egestas finibus. Sed ultrices nulla dui, vitae vulputate nulla facilisis at. Nunc non congue mauris, id cursus ipsum. Nullam fringilla nisl eu velit lacinia porttitor. Ut venenatis nibh libero, gravida vulputate metus volutpat vitae.</p>
```

A única diferença do exemplo anterior e seu problema é que usei apenas "#foo", como link. Se fosse em outra página (o que você quer), pode colocar o link completo mais a cerquilha e id.

Comment: O texto a baixo da imagem é um input não editavel, como eu faço pro texto desse input ir para no input da outra pagina???

Comment: Coloca seu código referente, na descrição.

Answer (score 0):

Bom galera, quero agradecer a quem se disponibilizou a responder, solucionei este problema de uma outro forma, não sei se é a melhor forma, mas foi solucionado em partes. Este nome que esta em um input a baixo de uma imagem, estou pegando ele usando uma classe Servlet e retornando para uma pagina JSP, de certa forma deu certo, porem um nome por exemplo "XXXX zz YYYY" esta chegando no JSP apenas "XXXX". Se tiverem alguma dica eu agradeço, mas obrigado a quem respondeu.

Comment: Desculpa galera, mas consegui resolver o problema de aparecer apenas o primeiro nome, obrigado pela atenção de voces e desculpa o encomodo